# Search DataTable with values from another table

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

I'm trying to search one `DataTable` with values from another`DataTable` using LINQ, but no progress so far... How to do it?

In example below i have `table`, in which i search, and `PlTable`, which has only one column; and i need to retrieve every row from `table`, in which the `Name` field contains at least one string of `Name` field in `PlTable`'s rows.

```
Dim ePlTable As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = PlTable.AsEnumerable()

Dim found = From row In table.AsEnumerable
            Where row(0).Contains(ePlTable)
            Select row
Return found.CopyToDataTable.Rows
```

Surely it does not work, as `.Contains` wants `String` as argument

Comment: What is the content of row(0)? Or do you want to check whether the name is found in `ePlTable`? (Besides that, I prefer to use the string (key) as index rather than the numeric index, it is less error prone, if the order of columns change.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Surely it does not work, as .Contains wants String as argument

That's exatly the problem, so use the strongly typed `Field` extension
 method to cast it to it's correct type and `Enumerable.Any` to look if at least one string is contained in this `Name`:

```
Dim strings = From row In PlTable Select row.Field(Of String)(0)
Dim found = From row In table.AsEnumerable
            Where strings.Any(Function(s) row.Field(Of String)("Name").Contains(s))
            Select row
Return found.CopyToDataTable()
```