# VB.Net Linq-to-datatable How to create a datatable based on an existing datable with filter

Tags: vb.net

I have a similar issue like in this link,

[Search DataTable with values from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005448/search-datatable-with-values-from-another-table/27002066#27002066)

Tim has given answer about this issue.

```
  Dim strings = From row In PlTable Select row.Field(Of String)(0)
  Dim found = From row In table.AsEnumerable
  Where strings.Any(Function(s) row.Field(Of String)("Name").Contains(s))
      Select row
  Return found.CopyToDataTable()
```

Since I am new to this, so please help. In my P1Table, there are many values for the only one column. Do these codes return a new datatable for every value from P1Table? Also, in my P1Table, the ePlTable column has string values that are matched only first 3 characters of a column in the table. Do these codes still work? The last question, when I debug it, it shows the parameter "s" in Function(s) has only one character? Why? Thanks

Comment: This would return all the rows from your `table` datatable where the field `Name` contains a string that matches with what you have in your `strings` collection (the first column in your `PlTable` DataTable)

Comment: Thanks John. Since I'd like to create a new datatable for each item in the P1Table, does that mean I should create a function and includes these codes and in the main program I will pass the parameter to it, like in this example?

    For i As Integer = 0 To dtTable1.Rows.Count - 1
            SelectIntoDataTable(P1Table.Rows(i).Item(0), table)
    Next

Comment: To understand what it is you want - You're looking to, for each row of `PlTable`, create a new datatable with the corresponding matching rows from `table`? If that is the case, what would you use those separate tables for and how would you want to store them? - FYI, the current code will return a **single** datatable where any of the rows from `PlTable` has a match in `table`

Comment: You understand it correctly. Once I get all datatables, I will manipulate data in each table. For example, I will count how many rows of each datatable, and pull out each column's data to show. Is there a way I can create all datatables I need? thank you.

Comment: I also have a question about Function(s) and Contains(s). I understand "s" is a parameter. But why it is a char type? I need it to be string type because I pass parameter as string type

Comment: Based upon what you're asking, `s` **should** be a string, not a `char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon what you wrote in your comments, although I'm very confused as to why you would want it this way and think you should rather look at your code a bit more and see if there's a nicer / neater solution (for example, using `DataViews` [that automatically allow for filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx)).

The way I would do this would look as follows:

```
Dim ReturnedTables As New List(Of DataTable)
Dim strings = From row In PlTable Select row.Field(Of String)(0)

For Each s As String In strings
    Dim Retval = From row In table.AsEnumerable
                 Where row.Field(Of String)("Name").Contains(s)
                 Select row

    If Retval.Count > 0 Then ReturnedTables.Add(Retval.CopyToDataTable)
Next
```

This will fill the variable `ReturnedTables` which will consist of separate DataTables as you mentioned wanting.

Again, note that this will be very memory intensive as you're actually creating a separate datatable for each iteration of the loop (rather than filtering), but it should do what you've requested.

Hope this helps!

---

**Additional:**

Based upon your question below, to get the number of rows from a specific datatable, it would look something long the lines of:

```
ReturnedTables(i).Rows.Count
```

And to get all the values from a specific field you would use the exact same syntax / logic as was used above to create the `strings` enumerable.

Hope that makes sense!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, John. Your codes make sense! Can you please give me one example to access to the List of datatable for counting how many rows in a specific datatable and to show values of a specific field. Thanks!

Comment: John, this code for access to a element of a datatable doesn't work:
    Debug.WriteLine("column1: {0}", ReturnedTables(i).Rows(i).Item(0))
Can you pls help? Thank you

Comment: @user3754205, how is it not working? Maybe try the `ToString()` method - `Debug.WriteLine("column1: {0}", ReturnedTables(i).Rows(j).Item(0).ToString())`. Also, I'm assuming you didn't really do this, but don't use `i` for both the datatable and the row enumerator.

Comment: that means I will need to use 2 for loops; one for I and one for J? I think it doesn't work because I run through for loop but I have datatables that are different rows.

Comment: @user3754205, you would definitely need 2 loops - one to loop through the datatables in the list and the other to loop through all the rows in that specific datatable you're dealing with - But **give it a try** and then post another question if  you get stuck...

Comment: I think I got it but NOT until you showed me to use the second for loop. Thanks a lot! Have a nice day